# rescue_from Koala exceptions

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, exception, koala

Beginner question perhaps:

I'm trying to check my user permissions from facebook with Koala. In some cases I'm going to get thrown an error. So I just want to catch it and redirect to re-authenticate.

```
  def check_facebook_permissions
    if token = current_user.try(:authentications).find_by_provider('facebook').try(:token)
      graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(token)
      permissions = graph.get_connections('me','permissions')
      session[:facebook] = {}
      session[:facebook][:ask_publish_actions] = true if permissions[0]['publish_actions'] != true && permissions[0]['publish_stream'] != true
    end
  rescue_from Koala::Facebook::APIError
    # Do something funky here
  end
```

I thought this was straightforward, but I'm never hitting my rescue. Instead I get:

```
Koala::Facebook::APIError (OAuthException: Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1324026000. The current unix time is 1324352685.):
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rescue_from` is not a syntactic construct of Ruby like `rescue` is - it is a normal function, and you need a block to go with it. In your code, no code is given, `rescue_from` gets executed and effectively skipped - what is after it has no bearing on any exceptions raised before it (just as if you put any other function, like `puts`, instead of `rescue_from`).

See an example of `rescue_from` use [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html).

To make this code work, you need the vanilla Ruby `rescue`:

```
rescue Koala::Facebook::APIError => e
```

Comment: aaaaa...that was killing me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for handling errors in Ruby is:

```
begin
  # do something that will throw an error
rescue StandardError => e # StandardError is the root class of most errors
  # rescue the error
end
```

Comment: `begin` is not needed if there is some other delimiter present; in this case, `def` suffices. `begin` is used when you want to restrict the rescuable part to a syntactic region which is not already in a `xxxx ... end` construction.